# Why does NSDecimalNumber.notANumber.intValue return 9?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, nsdecimalnumber

I found a bug in my code that is caused by `NSDecimalNumber.notANumber.intValue` returning 9, while I would expect `NaN` (as `floatValue` or `doubleValue` return). Does anybody know why?

[image]

Comment: There is no integer value which represents NaN.

Comment: @MartinR has this `9` something to do with maximal value for `Int64` (9223372036854775807)?

Comment: @RobertDresler Definitely not. I would guess this will have something to do with the binary value of `NaN` representation.

Comment: According to Apple doc "If you ask an NSNumber object for its value using a type that cannot hold the value, you get back an erroneous result", could this be it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it would make sense, for `Int32` it is `-2147483648`. But still, why not `-9223372036854775808` for `Int64` instead of `9`?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I learned a lot here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like mentioned by Joakim Danielson and noted in the [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber#1776614)

> ... Because numeric types have different storage capabilities, attempting to initialize with a value of one type and access the value of another type may produce an erroneous result ...

And since Swift's `Int` struct cannot represent NaN values, you get this erroneous result.

Instead you could use `Int`'s [Failable Initialiser](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID224) [`init(exactly:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2895386-init) that converts your NSDecimalNumber to an `Int?` that will either contain it's value or be `nil` if it is not representable by an `Int`.

```
let strangeNumber = NSDecimalNumber.notANumber          // nan
let integerRepresentation = Int(exactly: strangeNumber) // nil
```

Comment: In Swift you should use `Decimal.nan` anyway, not `NSDecimalNumber`.